# copying between variables in C

Tags: c, variables, copy

I want to copy an unsigned int value to a char[2] variable. I presume the copying is straight forward since both of them have the same size (16 bits). Here's my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    unsigned short a = 63488; //16 bit value which is 1111100000000000;
    unsigned char* b = malloc(2); 
    *b = a;
    printf("%d\n",b[0]); // I expect the lower part here which is 0
    printf("%d\n",b[1]); // I expect the higher part here which is 11111000
    return 0;
}
```

But my result shows zero values. Do I have to copy each part separately? Isn't there any other easier method to do that?

Thank you

Comment: This assumes that an integer on your platform is only 16 bits.  This really is not a safe assumption today.  You should expect most platforms to implement 32 bit integers at a minimum.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer While you're right about not making platform assumptions (see how I avoided this in my answer), note that he's using `short` which is 16 bits on every platform I can think of.

Comment: Ah, I didn't actually notice the short.  I just saw the "unsigned int" in the question. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to *interpret* the `short` as a `char` array, you don't even need to copy. Just cast:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    size_t i;
    unsigned short a = 63488;
    unsigned char* b = (unsigned char*)&a;    // Cast the address of a to
                                              // a pointer-to-unsgigned-char

    printf("Input value: %d (0x%X)\n", a, a);

    printf("Each byte:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(a); i++)
        printf("b[%d] = %d (0x%X)\n", i, b[i], b[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Werror so1.c && ./a.out
Input value: 63488 (0xF800)
Each byte:
b[0] = 0 (0x0)
b[1] = 248 (0xF8)
```

Note that I ran this on my x86 PC, which is a *little endian* machine, which is why the first byte is the low byte of the input.

Also note that my code also never makes assumptions about the size of `short`.

Comment: if compiled ` gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=c99 -Werror untitled.c && ./a.out`  then the result is:
`untitled.c: In function ‘main’:
untitled.c:13:19: error: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Werror=sign-compare]
     for (i = 0; i < sizeof(a); i++)
                   ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors`.  However, if correct declaration of `i` to `size_t i:` and correct `printf()` to `printf("b[%lu] = %d (0x%X)\n", i, b[i], b[i]);` then it works properly.  This reinforces the statement: always enable all warnings, then fix those warnings

Answer (score 3):

Try like this

```
memcpy(b, &a, sizeof(a));
```

Or

```
b[0] = a & 0xFF;
b[1] = (a >> 8) & 0xFF;
```

Note that `b` is of type `unsigned char` so assigning to `*b` should be a value of the same type or the value will be truncated.

Comment: Good explanation for the truncation, but I'm afraid your answer is incomplete: the OP should be warned on endianness issues.